# Casting a real number to Comparable in java?

Tags: java, casting, numbers, integer, comparable

Let´s say I have a method that inserts a number into a Binary Tree

```
public BinaryNode insert(Comparable x, BinaryNode t) {
    //Logic here
}

BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree();
```

How would I cast a number , for example 4 to match the right paremeters on this methods? Ex.

```
t.insert(4, t ) // I know this wont work, but I wanted to to something like this
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine - it'll be boxed into an integer. Sample code:

```
public class Test {

    static void foo(Comparable<?> c) {
        System.out.println(c.getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        foo(10);
    }
}
```

This works even if you use the raw type `Comparable`, although I'd recommend against that.

Admittedly I strongly suspect that you'd be better off making your `BinaryNode` (and presumably `BinaryTree`) class generic, at which point you'd have:

```
// You shouldn't need to pass in the node - the tree should find it...
BinaryTree<Integer> tree = new BinaryTree<Integer>();
tree.insert(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you pass new Integer(4) instead of 4 assuming you are using Java version prior to 5 (as you are saying it's not working).